# How to insert from another table and using PK to insert into multiple tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to copy info into another table but as each record is created I will be using a unique identity to generated a new PK. I also want to use that PK to insert into another table e.g.

INSERT INTO Table1(a, b)
SELECT a, b FROM TempTable

INSERT INTO Table2(id, description)
VALUES([PK From new record created in Table1], 'Test')

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. I am guessing here because there isn't much detail but take a look at the OUTPUT clause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should realize that your code can create more than one new record.

The following captures all the new ids into `@ids` and then inserts all of them into the new table:

```
declare @ids table (int id);

insert into table1(a, b) 
    output inserted.id into @ids
    select a, b 
    from TempTable;

insert into Table2(id, description) 
    select id, 'Test'
    from @ids;
```

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to give an idea...im looking for a while loop I guess, so that once the record is created I can use the PK to insert into other tables....not sure if that makes sense